# why does numpy array return wrong shape of sub arrays when indexing

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

An example is shown as follows:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a=np.zeros((288,512))
>>> x1,x2,y1,y2=0,16,0,16
>>> p=a[x1:x2][y1:y2]
>>> p.shape
(16, 512)
>>> p=a[x1:x2,y1:y2]
>>> p.shape
```

I try to query a patch from an array, ranging from columns 0 to 16, and rows 0 to 16. I index the array in two ways and get very different result. `a[x1:x2][y1:y2]` gives me the wrong result.

Why?

Thx for helping me!!!

Comment: Those are different methods.  With scalar indices they produce the same, but not with slices.  Look at `a[x1:x2]` by itself. Then apply the  y slice to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `a[x1:x2][y1:y2]`, you are slicing by rows twice. That is, `a[x1:x2]` will give you a shape `(16,512)`. The second slice operation in `a[x1:x2][y1:y2]` is slicing the result of the first operation and will give you the same result.

In the second case, when you do `a[x1:x2,y1:y2]`, you are slicing by the two dimensions of your 2-dimensional array.

**Important note**: If you have a 2-dimensional array and you slice like this:

```
a = np.zeros((10,15))
a[1:3].shape

Output:
(2, 15)
```

you will slice only by rows. Your resulting array will have 2 rows and the total number of columns (15 columns). If you want to slice by rows and columns, you will have to use `a[1:3, 1:3]`.

Answer (score 1):

The two methods of indexing you tried are not equivalent. In the first one (`a[x1:x2][y1:y2]`), you are essentially indexing the first axis twice. In the second, you are indexing the first and second axes.

`a[x1:x2][y1:y2]` can be rewritten as

```
p = a[x1:x2] # result still has two dimensions
p = p[y1:y2]
```

You are first indexing 0:16 in the first dimension. Then you index 0:16 in the first dimension of the result of the previous operation (which will simply return the same as `a[x1:x2]` because `x1==y1` and `x2==y2`).

In the second method, you index the first and second dimensions directly. I would not write it this way, but one could write it like this to contrast it with the first method:

```
a[x1:x2][:, y1:y2]
```